# Selecting Specific Cells in 3 different CollectionViews to perform a Segue to a specific View Controller

Tags: swift

I have 3 separate collectionViews in one view controller with 3 items in each collection view. I want the user to select 1 cell from each collectionView and depending on what is selected it segues to a specific view controller.

I know there's probably some logic involved I'm currently using " If, Else statements. I've also using didSelectItemAt using performSegueWithIdentifier for each collectionView's cell but, the segue always happens when the user just selects 1 cell in one collectionView i haven't figured out where to I'm going wrong.

Here's the code I've been working with;

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewRed: UICollectionView!

  @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewBlue: UICollectionView!

  @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewGreen: UICollectionView!

  var redColors = ["Red", "Infrared", "Crimson"]

  var blueColors = ["Blue", "Light Blue", " Navy Blue"]

  var greenColors = ["Green", "Lime Green", "Forest Green"]


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath: IndexPath) {

 if collectionView == self.collectionViewRed {

   let cellA = collectionViewRed.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as!     
   CollectionViewCell

   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowNextView", sender nil)

 } else if collectionViewBlue == self.collectionViewBlue {

   let cellB = collectionViewBlue.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! 
   CollectionViewCell

   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowNextView", sender: nil)

 } else if collectionView == self.collectionViewGreen {

   let cellC = collectionViewGreen.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as!   
   CollectionViewCell

}


}
```

When the user clicks on the "Red" in the Red CollectionView it performs the segue to the Next ViewController instead of when the user selects "Red", from the "redCollectionView, then "Blue" from the "blueCollectionView", and then finally "Green" from the "greenCollectionView" to perform the segue to the specific ViewController.

What code should I use instead in-order to allow the user to select 1 item from each collectionView then perform the segue?

Comment: What do you want to do if they choose Crimson, Blue. Lime Green...nothing?

Comment: The same thing as choosing any other combination, but it figured if I segue choosing one set of colors, I should be able to do using another set of colors

Comment: OK.  I asked because there would be different logic depending on whether the idea was to know there were selections versus knowing there were *specific* selections.

Comment: What is the logic involved in making specific selections, at specific Indexes?, because ultimately that's what I need in-order to perform the segue to specific viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You Should have 3 Bools storing the states of the selected cells for all the collection view

Initialise these to false

```
var isFirstCollectionViewSelected = false
var isSecondCollectionViewSelected = false
var isThirdCollectionViewSelected = false

// You can also use this for the states, in that case you would not even need the above variables 
var firstSelectedIndex: Int?
```

So your `didSelectItemAt` will look like

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath: IndexPath) {

 if collectionView == self.collectionViewRed {
   isFirstCollectionViewSelected = true

   self.firstSelectedIndex = indexPath.row

   // Add logic here when this cell is selected  

 } else if collectionView == self.collectionViewBlue {
   isSecondCollectionViewSelected = true

   // Add logic here when this cell is selected  

 } else if collectionView == self.collectionViewGreen {
   isThirdCollectionViewSelected = true

   // Add logic here when this cell is selected 

 }

 performSegueIfAllAreSelected()
}
```

Where `performSegueIfAllAreSelected()` would be

```
func performSegueIfAllAreSelected() {

  if isFirstCollectionViewSelected, isSecondCollectionViewSelected, isThirdCollectionViewSelected { 
     if self.firstSelectedIndex == 1 {  
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowNextView", sender: nil)
     } else {
     //
     }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I'll try this set of tomorrow morning

Comment: This blocked of code worked, however im a still a bit confused as to how i set it to where i select a specific cells to perform the segue (i.e., i select the cells at index 0, in the 1st collectionview, index 1 in the 2nd collectionView, and then finally index 0, in the 3rd collectionView

Comment: @Iboykin11 you would have to save the selected index for the collectionView where i've written 
`// Add logic here when this cell is selected `

then use that value to navigate to the desired controller in `performSegueIfAllAreSelected ()`

Comment: Thank you for the edited answer its working much better, however when trying to add specific indexes I've gotten different errors for each different way I have tried to implement them where you stated "add logic here when cell is selected"

Comment: @Iboykin11 Point me to some code you have errors with, edit the question accordingly

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath: IndexPath) {

 if collectionView == self.collectionViewRed {
   isFirstCollectionViewSelected = true

   self.firstSelectedIndex = indexPath.row

   firstSelectedIndex = [0,1,2] 

which gives me the error  "Cannot assign '[Int]' to type 'Int?'
then I went back and change firstSelectedIndex = [Int?], which then gives me the error "Cannot assign [Int?] to type 'Int'

Comment: @Iboykin11  firstSelectedIndex  is of type `Int` so it cant store an `[Int]` (an array of Int), this is very basic see some tutorials regarding some basics so you can ask better questions. The Actual Question has been answered here.